# Best way to bind multiple DomainDataSources to a RadGridView selection change

Tags: silverlight, binding, wcf-ria-services, radgridview, query-string

I have a master grid, used for finding items, then a set of 3 grids below it to shown parallel sets of related details for the selected row using simple Name Value pairs.

### It looks like this:

[image]

When I breakpoint the Domain Service the parameters from the selected row are passed to it correctly, but the child grids are showing entries unrelated to the data returned.

### A debug version of one of the 3 Domain Service methods looks like:

```
    public IEnumerable<NameValuePair> GetRandNameValues(int randId)
    {
        // If I breakpoint here the values in randId are 
        // correct for the selected master row

        List<NameValuePair> result = new List<NameValuePair>();
        result.Add(new NameValuePair("[ID]", randId.ToString()));
        ...
        return result;
    }
```

### An example of one of the 3 child RadGridViews is:

```
            <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="randGridView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGroupPanel="False"  RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=randDataSource, Path=Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Value" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

### An example of one of the 3 child DomainDataSource objects is:

```
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource Name="randDataSource" Height="0" Width="0"
        QueryName="GetRandNameValuesQuery">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:RandDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
             <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="randId"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=masterGridView, Path=SelectedItem.Rand_ID}"/>
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Which should return the key value passed, in this test case, but it always shows a value of 0 like this:
[image]

The 0 is from the initial case where nothing is selected. Other rows in the detail grid change, but not to the correct records. In fact they seem to alternate between a small set of values relating to a couple of master rows.... weird.

The DomainService is being called at the correct times with the correct keys, but the return values are wrong.

### What triggers the update of the child grids? What am I missing? Why are they showing old data in some, but not all rows?

### Update:

I added a handler for the `LoadedData` event on the datasource and find when I breakpoint it the entities within it are the wrong values... i.e. not what the domain service selected:

```
    private void randDataSource_LoadedData(object sender, LoadedDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HasError)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString(), "Rand Load Error", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK);
            e.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        }
    }
```

When I replaced the cross-binding to the Grid selection, shown above, with 3 separate load calls on 3 separate domain contexts it works fine. The problem seems to be in binding DomainDataSource parameters to the selection change on the Grid.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: I have one small suggestion regarding the GetRandNameValue method. Instead of IEnumerable<T> is better to return List<T>, because you are doing downcasting which is redundant in this case (List already implements IEnumerable).

Comment: @MajoB: That was just for the example. Different calls for the different columns return the data direct from tables, so I kept with IEnumerable<T>. If that could be a cause of the problem though let me know.